Controlling time in a HTML page for inclusion in rendering
The idea is to render a web page inside my video editor which can use WebView2 in WinApp SDK.
When the page has no animations then I can take a screenshot of the hosting window and render it as a bitmap all right.
When the page has an animation, then I should be able to control the time programmatically.
That is, if say given a CSS animation:
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

<div></div>

The animation of a 4s should be controlled programmatically by my application, e.g. tell the webpage to render to 2s should directly go to the 2s (and stop).
Of course, I could try directly embedding the Chromium engine and experiment. But, before that, I would like to check for any easier alternatives:

Can this be done with JavaScript?

I'm taking a look to the WebView2 Chromium API on Microsoft's site. I can't find any time-controlling mechanism.

Ideally, I should be able to control other parameters programmatically, like mouse events (yes, I guess I've already gone too far). I'm taking a look at ICoreWebView2PointerInfo, which also has a put_Time(), but for pointer events, not generic.


From a quick view of webview2.h in the Windows APP SDK, I didn't hit anything interesting (so far).

I don't think webview has any time controlling/sourcing facility. You can change animation duration using javascript (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_js_animation-duration) but it won't be generic if you don't own page you would have for example to scan the page for all animations before controlling them (in javascript) and javascript is easy to use from WebView2. But there may be some difficult case, like restarting animations (https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/), animations using setInterval, requestAnimationFrame, etc.
